# Xtend: Create string list

Tags: generics, xtend

How do I create a variable with type `List<String>` in Xtend?

```
var list = Lists::newArrayList()
list.add( "xxx" )
```

doesn't work; the type in the `add()` isn't propagated back.

```
var list = Lists::newArrayList() as List<String>
```

gives an exception at runtime.

How do I create lists of a certain type in Xtend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of Xtend do you use?

```
var list = newArrayList
list.add('')
```

works for me (2.4.3).

Also `var List<String> list = newArrayList` will do the trick.

Comment: I'm on 2.3. Specifying the type between `var` and the name works.